# How to escape hexadecimal characters before model binding during deserialization in asp.net core mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How to escape hexadecimal unicode characters before model binding itself?

```
public IActionResult Create([FromBody]Student student){

}
```

while posting student, the student json has hexadecimal unicode characters. How to remove them before model binding happens?

Lets say the student json object looks like this:
{"name": "John\u0003xxx"}

Answer (score 0):

what about custom model binder ?
i suggest you can create custom binder and escape this values

this link can help you

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding